# Missing field "priceValidUntil" (in "offers")and Alternate page with proper canonical tag issues in my website on google search console

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, google-search-console

I hope you're all doing well. I'm reaching out to the community for some guidance and suggestions regarding the issues I've encountered in my [Shopify store](https://poolnoodles.store)'s Google Search Console.

Missing field "priceValidUntil" (in "offers"): Google Search Console is flagging a missing field "priceValidUntil" within the "offers" section of my product markup. I understand that this field is related to indicating the expiration date of a special price offer. However, I'm unsure how to properly implement it within my Shopify store's product schema.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITRAN.png)

Alternate page with proper canonical tag: Google Search Console is highlighting an issue related to an alternate page with a proper canonical tag. It appears that there might be inconsistencies or conflicts with canonical tags across different pages of my website.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkD2W.png)

Despite trying various solutions and implementing several troubleshooting steps, including re-adding product information, meticulously reviewing product descriptions, and ensuring all features are correctly configured multiple times, I'm disappointed to report that the error in my Shopify store persists.

Answer (score 0):

**priceValidUntil**

If you don't have a way to control how long prices are valid until, ignore the issue. If you do, it indicates that you may be able to get Google to use that information.

**Alternate page with proper canonical tag**

I believe this is common with Shopify product pages. If Google finds multiple URLs for the same content, it will pick one of them, and the others will be in this class. Shopify creates different product URL links from its collection pages, thus causing this scenario.

Comment: may its impact badly on my site performance? because i am growing my site with SEO